# File upload issue using http::geturl in Tcl contain http-2.9 package

Tags: http, tcl

I am using http::geturl to POST a Binary file using these command

```
set fid [open $filename RDONLY]
fconfigure $fid -buffering full -encoding binary -translation binary

::http::geturl {http://10.39.51.221:11009/api/v1/sessions/1/ixnetwork/files?filename=test} \
    -type application/octet-stream \
    -querychannel $fid \
    -binary true \
    -headers {X-Api-Key 00000000000000000000000000000000 IxNetwork-Lib {IxNetwork tcl client v.IXTCLPROTOCOLVERSION} Host 10.39.51.221} \
    -timeout 180000
```

This code was working properly against Tcl-8.6.6 with http-2.8.9.
But the client hangs when using the same code against against same Tcl-8.6.6 with different http package (http-2.9);
I feel this behavior change due to [this change](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/info/1876e25b9ced4520).

Earlier `-translation` was set only as binary (http-2.8.9)

```
fconfigure $state(-querychannel) -blocking 1 -translation binary
```

whereas currently `-translation` also pull from socket (http-2.9)

```
lassign [fconfigure $sock -translation] trRead trWrite
fconfigure $state(-querychannel) -blocking 1 \
        -translation [list $trRead binary]
```

Same code is working properly when reverted to (`fconfigure $state(-querychannel) -blocking 1 -translation binary`) in http-2.9 code base.
Please suggest any change in my code to run against both http-2.8.6 as well as http-2.9.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug. [Please file it here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktnew). I think you have to log in first (it's an antispam measure) but you can use a pseudonymous login when reporting issues. (The reason for filing there? It ensures that it gets seen by the right set of eyes.)

Comment: Thanks @DonalFellows   I have filed an issue https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/f81beca7afabb3d2d395bd979607eda184622f7a